# Apple Push Certificates

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

My app has 3 provisioning profiles:

- **Ios development**
- **Beta**
- **Release**

First one is used for development, second for test flight and third for the app store.
Also there are 2 App IDs

- **com.sansasystem.dribble**
- **com.sansasystem.dribble-dev**

**Ios development** and **Beta** profiles both use **com.sansasystem.dribble-dev**. 
I enabled push notifications capability and generated sandbox APNS certificate.
However, pushes do come when I sign the app with **Ios Development** profile, but don't when signed with **Beta**.
Is it something I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the app and also use the same cert & prov-profile to sign with "com.sansasystem.dribble-dev" for the beta app.

1. The push notification and cert is tied to the single bundle ID and the app compiled and bundled profile. If you are looking in bundle settings for XCode project, do check that the Automatic provisioning is not selected. Mostly due to this the profile may get auto-generated and not with APNS.
2. Also, check the Beta Target "Capabilities" tab is enabled for Push notification button turned on.
3. Lastly, check the Profile used by the actual beta target. Go to Project Build Settings --> General tab --> in that there is a profile drop down and next to that the (i) button, click that and you will be able to read the profile details and info related to the prov-file used.

If that is not same as the one you have created then I suggest use the Manual signing way and untick the automatic provisioning profile check box to make life more specific to get the error.